# PHP Loops with nested loops

Tags: php

having a few issues getting this nested loop to work.

I am building a screen which will display the users room types (from database) and then a set of tabs will be generated to display the rates which are linked to each separate room type.

This part is for the tabs:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM room_types WHERE session_id='$sessthis'");

                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                              echo "<div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane' id='" . $row['name'] . "_" . $row['tableid'] . "'>";
$get_data = MySQLi_query($con, "SELECT room_types.tableid, room_types.name, rates_1.rate_name, rates_1.rate_descr, rates_1.rate_monpr 
                                  FROM room_types INNER JOIN rates_1
                                  ON room_types.tableid=rates_1.room_type WHERE room_types.session_id='$sessthis' AND rates_1.session_id='$sessthis' AND rates_1.room_type=room_types.tableid");

while($row_rates = mysqli_fetch_array($get_data))
                            {
                                echo "<div class='ui cards' style='width:100%'>
                                          <div class='card'>
                                            <div class='content'>
                                              <div class='header'>" . $row_rates['rate_name'] . "</div>
                                              <div class='meta'>" . $row_rates['name'] . "</div>
                                              <div class='description'>
                                                " . $row_rates['rate_descr'] . "
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                          </div>";
                            }                              
                              echo "</div>";
                            }
```

What I want it to do is open the tab, then loop through and display the rates and then close the tab and loop back through until all rooms have been displayed. The rates table has a column called `room_type` where I store the room type's `tableid`

what its doing at the minute is outputting the correct number of tabs but all rates are in every tab regardless of type. Can anyone point me in the right direction for ensuring, for example, the rates associated with the single room are only outputted to the tab for the single room?

Many thanks.

EDIT: See post below, issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a brainwave, it hit me when I re-read the question... sorry, friday afternoons! added a variable to the outer loop which defines the room type id and then added WHERE room_type=$type to the nested loop